# extjs store not loaded bu server returns json response

Tags: extjs

My extjs store is not loaded even if the server reutrns a correct json response.
I checked that the fields return from the response has the same names as the fields defined in the store.
The grid is just blank.

What can I check?

Comment: post your store definition and a response snippet and maybe we can help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check you are returning an array of objects to ExtJS. If you are returning an object, containing the array of objects as a field, make sure you specify rootProperty for JsonReader to find the array. Make sure you are using correct data reader (i.e. JsonReader).

You may also try adding data from response manually into store via `add` to check that the data fits in well.

Comment: Thanks very much!! rootProperty  was missing